# PHP cURL is slow

Tags: php, curl

I've seen quite some topics about this issue, but nothing is really useful to me so forgive me for starting yet another topic about this.

My website runs about 20 cURL cycles in order to get build up. I like cURL because you can hide content away but crawlers can see it. I had a problem with using includes so I had to use cURL as the replacement. Each time cURL gets loaded with an URL with parameters. All URL's are  linking to **local** php files.

At average the website requires four seconds to load.

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Using cURL as a replacement for includes??? How? Why?

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620272/how-can-i-speed-up-curl-tasks

Comment: "I had a problem with using includes"... and this problem was what?

Comment: Your reasoning does not make sense: `curl` and `include` run server-side and for a crawler to see something, you need to get it client-side. And you can do that a whole lot more efficient using `include` than hitting your own server with http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems you will come across using cURL, rather than using standard PHP includes. Here is a summary.

Queuing - with 20 requests to execute in your code, each request will delay the creation of your page. The request comes with its own overheads in terms of waiting and loading.

Database - rather than opening a connection to the database, grabbing all your data and closing the connection, you will need to open a connection perhaps 20 times (depending on whether the pages need database access). Creating and releasing a connection will cost you time.

I would wager that whatever you are doing with cURL you could do with an include. When you include a file in PHP it has access to all of the variables that are currently in scope - so you don't need to pass them in a querystring, you can just use them from the second file...

*example.php*

```
$example = 'This is an example';
include_once('other.php');
```

*other.php*

```
echo $example; // writes: This is an example
```

Comment: Good point about the databases. Indeed It's opening the database alot of times.
About my includes problem. Keep in mind I'm also sending parameters with it ($_GET['X'] = 1; for example before the include). I also tried the ob_get_contents function.

I had some weird bug that the script is skipping certain includes in while loops. Maybe it doesn't like many $_GET changes but it's a mystery to me. cURL is getting everything it's been given but it's slow.
Thanks so far.

Comment: use classes and functions if you want to use parameters